# Magento 2: Set order status to complete programmatically results in "Please provide payment for the order"

Tags: magento2, order-status

i would like to set order to complete programmatically after they have been processed in another software. This is the typical code i found all over the internet:

```
$orderId = 1000120319;
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order') ->load($orderId);
$orderState = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_COMPLETE;
$order->setState($orderState)->setStatus($orderState);
$order->save();
```

All i get is this result:

> Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException: Please provide payment for the order.

What i have to do, to set the payment completed as well?
Thanks for your help in advanced

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Use loadByIncrementId instead of load.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'll need to create an invoice for it first, though I don't have code handy for that.  Here is an example solution for that: https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-programmatically-create-invoice-in-magento2/

Comment: thanks for your advice. that was my first idea. But $order->canInvoice() is false and if we try to create an invoice anyway we will end with "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function canCapture() on null"